# How to get the last occurrence of the duplicated array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with duplicates:

```
nameList = [{name:"name1", filename:"filename1"}, {name:"name2", filename:"filename2"}, {name:"name3", filename:"filename2"}]
```

and I want to retain only the unique item but the last item only. I want:

```
nameList = [{name:"name1", filename:"filename1"}, {name:"name3", filename:"filename2"}]
```

I have tried:

```
var flags = {};
resultNameList = nameList.filter(function(entry) {
    if (flags[entry.filename]) {
        return false;
    }
    flags[entry.filename] = true;
    return true;
});
```

but it retains only the first occurrence of the duplicate. How can I get the last occurrence?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: In the first object it key name is `file`. In rest of the object it is `filename`. Please confirm which one is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduce an object indexed by the `filename` property, overwriting the previous item at that key in the accumulator if it exists - this ensures that after all iterations, the object's values are composed only of the latest occurrence of a given filename. Then take the values of the accumulator:

```js
const nameList = [{
  name: "name1",
  filename: "filename1"
}, {
  name: "name2",
  filename: "filename2"
}, {
  name: "name3",
  filename: "filename2"
}];

const output = Object.values(nameList.reduce((a, item ) => {
  a[item.filename] = item;
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```

Note that key-value pairs in an object must be separated by `:`, not `=`.

The input given in the comment below looks to work as desired too:

```js
const nameList = [{
  name: "name1",
  filename: "filename1"
}, {
  name: "name3",
  filename: "filename2"
}];

const output = Object.values(nameList.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.filename] = item;
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I only returns: {name:"name3", filename="filename2"}. What about {name:"name1",filename:"filename1"}, which is also unique?

Comment: I changed the first item from `file` to `filename` per you edit in the question, but it still looks to work as expected - just press the "Run code snippet" button as in the answer. The output is `[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "filename": "filename1"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "filename": "filename2"
  }
]`. That's correct, isn't it?

Comment: I edited that input into a second snippet in the answer, but it looks to perform as desired too: press "Run code snippet" and you get `[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "filename": "filename1"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "filename": "filename2"
  }
]`

Comment: Depending on the requirements, a better approach could be `Array.from(nameList.reduce((result, object) => { result.set(object.filename, object); return result; }, new Map()).values());`, using [`Map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), so the order stays the same as in the original array and doesn’t change around due to Object key ordering semantics.